# DatastoreInputReader using entity kind with ancestor

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there a way to use the standard `DatastoreInputReader` from AppEngine's mapreduce with entity kind requiring `ancestors` ?

Let's say I have an entity kind `Domain` with ancestor kind `SuperDomain` (useful for transactions), where do I specify in `mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline` how to use a specific `SuperDomain` entity as ancestor to all queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot specify an ancestor for the `DatastoreInputReader` -- except for a namespace -- so the pipeline will always go through all your `Domain` entities in a given namespace.

Comment: Does anybody knows workaround (or custom implementation?) of ``DatastoreInputReader`` to allow filtering on ancestor?